# Gradle dependency conflict on docker but running fine locally

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, build.gradle, docker-image, transitive-dependency

I'm using a gradle project, with guava version defined in repo.build.gradle as 32.0.0-jre but guava version 18 is being detected in the scan reports for the docker image of the repo, for the war file created in a module(core) within the repo(containing libraries of core module) and it(version 18 of guava) is not detected in the dependency tree.Any suggestions on how to find guava v18 is a transitive dependency for which library?

This is how the depency is defined in the repo.build.gradle

```
  configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            dependencySubstitution {
                substitute module('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic') using module("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4jVersion}")
                substitute module('ch.qos.logback:logback-core') using module("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4jVersion}")
                substitute module('org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j') using module("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:${log4jVersion}")
            }

           .
           .

            force 'com.google.guava:guava:32.0.0-jre'
            force 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.8'
           .
           . 
        }
allprojects {
    dependency{
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:32.0.0-jre"
   }
}
```

force 'com.google.guava:guava:32.0.0-jre'
I also excluded guava module from other libraries that were importing an older version of guava as per dependency tree.